# What is the best method for organizing geographical/city content in WordPress?

Tags: wordpress, tags, geolocation, categories, geo

I want to create a news contributor network similar to that of yahoo.com. It will have categories such as events, sports, fashion, etc but I want the content organized into different cities. However, I would like some content to have the ability of being shared across all cities. What is the best way to structure this or set this up in wordpress?

Comment: Will you be using default posts, also do you want to assign cities as you do categories?

Comment: Sorry, I understand this posts is so old but I am still interested in knowing the best solution. I do plan to use the default posts as well as custom post types. Do you think a viable solution would be to use a custom posts type (ie. Articles) that mimics the default posts but includes an additional city selection field via dropdown menu?

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing your complete situation, one solution may be to have categories used for topical reasons (as you already have) and have tags used for cities.

Answer (score 0):

Adding this after your latest comment.

One solution would be to register a custom taxonomy for Cities.

You could assign this taxonomy to default and any custom post types you have. This would function the same as Wordpress categories do and you could assign a city yo any post.

The advantage of this users could then view all post from a selected city.

https://codex.wordpress.org/Taxonomies

The Wordpress codex should have everything you need to get this set up.